# Can't build Drools examples from 'Drools JBoss Rules 5.0 Developer's Guide' using maven, unable to download artifact

Tags: java, build, jboss, maven-2, drools

I have some strange trouble while I'm trying to build examples from "Drools JBoss Rules 5.0 Developer's Guide". I try to run this examples doing step by step instruction from readme file(similar instruction is at: http://code.google.com/p/droolsbook/ )

I get following logs:

command: mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[INFO] Reactor build order:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]   Drools Book Parent                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]   Banking Core                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[INFO]   Validation                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO]   ETL with iBatis                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[INFO]   DSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO]   Decision Tables                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[INFO]   Ruleflow                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[INFO]   Stateful Rules                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[INFO]   Complex Event Processing                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[INFO]   Drools Flow                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[INFO]   Integration                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[INFO]   Sample Application                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]   Testing                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[INFO]   Performance                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom                                                                                                              
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org                                                
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom                                                                                                         
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0.2' from repository repository.jboss.com (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Authorization failed: Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom                                                                                                                                                    
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom                                                                                                              
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org                                                
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                              
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  repository.jboss.com (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 26 14:41:02 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Similar error I get when I run 'mvn clean install' 
(http://pastebin.com/FHQ4QqBH)

Thanks for any advice, gadon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is not related to Drools but to the configuration of your connection to Maven Central Repository. As you can see it can't download the maven compiler plugin. Please check your connection.

Comment: Thanks, on the website above hash been released new examples. Unfortunately with given in README file command:  mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true it couldn't build again. Happily with: mvn clean install every module has build successfully. Why is that? And additionally why is that all have build properly, but just one could be imported to eclipse? (only one got eclipse nature) Regards.

Comment: In the provided example you have:

`You can also build all examples and run all tests from command line. Go to the droolsBookParent project and execute:
mvn clean install `

so I can't find this **eclipse:eclipse** switch.

In general it is not good practice to add eclipse files to such examples because if smb uses InteliJ or Netbeans such a file is useless for him. You can import each of the modules separately by using **File->Import->Existing Maven Projects** and provide a folder of a submodule

Comment: If you find that my answer is a good one please close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some time has passed and for others who will have problem to run sample application from book (becouse of lack experience, like me), following short tutorial.

1. Use the maven >= 3.0.4.
2. Follow steps in README.
3. Download spring framework and copy from them spring-form.tld to WEB-INF\
4. Add to build path jstl jar.
5. Copy jstl jar to WEB-INF\lib
6. Run application on tomcat server.

Hope this helps.